# Looping a cout until valid input is provided?

Tags: loops, input, while-loop, cout, cin

```
char answer;
cout << "Launch simulation? (Y/N) : ";
cin  >> answer;
if (answer == 'N')
{
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
else if (answer == 'Y')
{
    // do something, calculations display page
}
else
{
cout << "Invalid input, enter 'Y' or 'N'." << endl;
while (answer != 'Y' || answer != 'N'){
    cin.getline(answer, 1);
}
```

I've probably over complicated it, but how can I make the *cout << "Launch simulation? (Y/N) : ";* loop until either 'Y' or 'N' is entered with the *"Invalid input, enter 'Y' or 'N'."* message.

'N' would return back to a menu page.

Even better would be so only the inputs 'Y' and 'N' were enter-able so a while loop would not be required and the question never repeated but I'd have no idea where to start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement

`while (answer != 'Y', 'N');`

doesn't actually do anything.

However, you probably meant

```
char answer = 'S'; // or some other char not 'Y', 'N'
cout << "Launch simulation? (Y/N) : ";

cout << "Invalid input, enter 'Y' or 'N'." << endl;
while (answer != 'Y' || answer != 'N'){
cin  >> answer;
}
//other stuff
```

Comment: I'm receiving this: error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::getline(_Elem *,std::streamsize)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'char' to 'char *'                                              `cout << "Invalid input, enter 'Y' or 'N'." << endl;
while (answer != 'Y' || answer != 'N'){
    cin.getline(answer, 1);
}`

Comment: How have you defined `variable`?

Comment: I've got the `char answer;` above the `cout << "Launch simulation? (Y/N) : ";` ?

Comment: remove `variable` and type `answer`

Comment: It doesn't loop it seems, why the `char answer = 'S'` ?

Comment: It's a dummy value. Without initializing,  it holds an unpredictable value.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be keep all the logic inside infinite while loop and then break from it when your condition is fulfilled e.g

```
char answer;
while(TRUE)
{
    cout << "Launch simulation? (Y/N) : ";
    cin  >> answer;
    if (answer == 'N')
    {
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    else if (answer == 'Y')
    {
        // do something, calculations display page
        return 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "Invalid input, enter 'Y' or 'N'." << endl; 
}
```